# Looking for a way to replace table name in query with Declaring Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Would like to know if its possible to replace one of the table name **DCI_ARD** by declaring a variable in head for the following query.

Have tried multiple ways, but the issue I am encountering is that I have multiple ' within the same query and it breaks off the declaration.

ie.      CONCAT('(',M.ManufacturerID,')',

ie.      STRING_AGG(CategoryID, ',') as CategoryID

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT [id]
          ,[brandaaiaid]
          ,M.ManufacturerID
          ,CONCAT('(',M.ManufacturerID,')',exppartno) AS TempManufacturerSKU
          ,[company]
          ,[fromyear]
          ,[toyear]
          ,[makename]
          ,[modelname]
          ,[submodelname]
          ,[engbase]
          ,[partterminologyname]
          ,[position]
          ,[exppartno]
          ,[mfrlabel]
      FROM DCI_ARD AS DS
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Manufacturer] AS M ON DS.brandaaiaid = M.AAIAID

      ) AS T

      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ProductVariant] AS PV ON T.TempManufacturerSKU = PV.ManufacturerPartNumber
      LEFT JOIN 
      (select ProductId, STRING_AGG(CategoryID, ',') as CategoryID
    from productCategory
    GROUP BY ProductId) as PC ON PV.ProductID = PC.ProductID ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, you appear to ask "can i replace a table name with a variable?" (no, you can't by the way; not without Dynamic SQL and there's a lot of considerations you need to make before that) but then reference `CONCAT` and `STRING_AGG` which are a scalar function and table-value function respectively. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks for replying! i am try to make the main table for the join global in the head of the procedure, which is dbo.DCI_ARD

Answer (score 0):

> Have tried multiple ways, but the issue I am encountering is that I have multiple ' within the same query and it breaks off the declaration.

Based on this I'm assuming that you're trying to build up a string and use sp_executesql, in which case any single quotes that appear in the SQL will need to be escaped by doubling them up. For example, if you wanted to run this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('(','Test',')') FROM MyTable
```

Using sp_executesql:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT CONCAT(''('',''Test'','')'') FROM MyTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString
```